# Not able to show the xlsx reports in webbrowser

Tags: 2010, web

I am not able to display the xlsx reports in web browser .

It displays an alert as to open,save,save ....

If the URL is host site/myreport.xlsx it shows an alert ...

If the URL is given as host site/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id = myreport.xlsx&DefaultItemOpen=1 . then it gets opened directly in the web browser directly .

Please assist me how to overcome this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check that the excel service application is installed and configured correctly then I think you need to add the document library path as a allowed path in excel services configuration.